# Flow type for React props.children (union Element | Array)

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, flow-typed

I have a container component and it's props type with children property:

```
type Props = {
    children: Array<React.Element<any>> | React.Element<any>,
    settings: string | Object
};
```

Container can contain the only one React.Element or multiple and depends on that it should choose the right operation.

In the render function I have something like that:

```
const children = this.props.children;

if ( _.isArray(children) ) {
    return _.map(children, (child, key) => checkListComponent(child, key));
}

else if ( _.isObject(children) ) {
    return checkListComponent(children);
}
```

The main function is that:

```
const checkListComponent = (child: React.Element<any>, key) => {
        return child.props.list
            ? React.cloneElement(child, key ? { options, key } : { options })
            : child;
    };
```

And after all I get a Flow error in **else if**

```
return checkListComponent(children);
```

**Flow: array type. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of React$Element.**

It seems to ignore possible type of non Array for the children prop. I found [issue on Github](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1330) about union Array and Object type but there is nothing.

Is there any solution for that situation?

**UPD:**

The same problem I have with **props.settings**, it can be an API url to fetch settings object from the server or a direct settings object. When I call an axios.get(settings) (obviously check before that **props.settings** is a string for now) Flow ignores possible string type and complains that **Object** given instead of string. **BUT** in the next line when I check settings for an object type and set container state

```
this.setState({ settings: this.props.settings });
```

It complains that **String** given instead of **Object**.

How it is possible and what can I do with that? I can but don't want to have two different props for settings API and Object. And definitely this is impossible for the **props.children** part of a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flow has no way to know that `_.isArray` returning `true` means that `children` is an array, and the same applies to `_.isObject`. Your code should work as

```
const children = this.props.children;

if (Array.isArray(children) ) {
  return children.map((child, key) => checkListComponent(child, key));
} else {
  return checkListComponent(children);
}
```

since `Array.isArray` is standard and Flow can know that in the `else` block `children` must be the the non-array type in your union.

Comment: Thank, that works. But one more question, obviously Flow has no way to know about lodash functions as they are but I have flow-typed for lodash (4.x.x) and there is a declaration `isString(value: string): true;
    isString(value: number|bool|Function|void|null|Object|Array<any>): false;` This is for a string and for the Object and Array there is just `any` but as I said in the UPD checking for a string with lodash is also not working. Why? Native checking is working good with the Flow but I want to make clear for myself how Flow working with declaration and etc.

Comment: Generally when checking the type of something, you'll want to stick to the core language stuff like `typeof`. I don't know if Flow is smart enough to interpret that Flow declaration. [They are in the process of experimenting with syntax](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/34) to let libraries do that kind of thing, but I don't think it is official yet.